# Code in AsyncTask isn't executing

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, execution

I have an `AsyncTask` which is executed just before my application quits. It gets the location and also parses my layout xml file. The location is retrieved but the parsing doesn't get executed.

Calling `AsyncTask` in my `Main Activity`:

```
public void quitApplication()
    {       
        FinishProcess fProcess = new FinishProcess();
        fProcess.execute(this);
}
```

`AsyncTask`:

```
public class FinishProcess extends AsyncTask<Main, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Main... params) {
        LocationHandler lh = new LocationHandler();
        try {
            lh.getLocationSingle(null, params[0]);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        parseXML(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    private void parseXML(Main params)
    {
        String ANDROID_ID = "android:id";       
        Resources resources = params.getResources();

        try {
            InputStream fXmlFile = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.pages);

            //Reads xml file and gets the node types and attributes
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);   
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    System.out.println(eElement.getNodeName());
                }
            }

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Catch");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is quitting after starting this process, then perhaps the main thread is dying while the background one (`AsyncTask`) is running, thereby orphaning it. If this needs to be done during shutdown try doing it in `Application.onTerminate` without the `AsyncTask` thread.

Comment: Using Application.onTerminate you just can't be sure that it will be called.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry I overlooked. Actually it seems `onTerminate` is only called in the emulator, never on a production device.

Comment: That said. Where is this async task called from right now? You can try calling `parsexml` from the same location minus the background thread. That one is sure a problem.

Comment: It's also a kind a bad idea, i suppose adding onPreExecute and onPostExecute methods to AsyncTask will do the trick, but i'm not sure